# Replacing RowMapper object with java 8 lambda expression

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate class in my project.I have the following code:

```
       List<PersonDTO> personList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<PersonDTO>() {

            @Override
            public PersonDTO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) throws SQLException {
                PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO ();
                personDTO.setPerId(rs.getString("COL_ONE"));  
                personDTO.setIdTypeCd(rs.getString("COL_TWO")); 
                return personDTO;
            }
        });
```

Now I want to replace the anonymous class `RowMapper` with java8 lambda expression something like this:

```
Runnable r1 = () -> {
        System.out.println("My Runnable");
    };
```

Is it possible?

Comment: that `throws SQLException` is something that will make the transformation a bit more verbose

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK `RowMapper` is a functional interface, so this would work. lambda expression can't declare checked exceptions, so you will need to wrap that...

```
jdbcTemplate.query(query, (ResultSet rs, int rowNumber) -> {
            PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO ();
            personDTO.setPerId(rs.getString("COL_ONE"));  
            personDTO.setIdTypeCd(rs.getString("COL_TWO")); 
            return personDTO;
});
```

The comments are spot on: since that functional interface already declares to throw the exception, there is no need to catch it.

Comment: `RowMapper::mapRow` declares that it can throw `SQLException`s, so I presume that the lambda body does not need to wrap thrown `SQLException`s into `RuntimeException`s (see [this example](https://github.com/britter/java8-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/java8examples/lambdas/SpringJdbcSupportWithLambdas.java), wherein the lambda is calling `ResultSet::getString`, an `SQLException`-throwing method.)

Comment: Lambda expressions can’t declare checked exceptions, but they don’t need to. The functional interface already does. You can simply use `(rs,rowNumber) -> { PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO(); personDTO.setPerId(rs.getString("COL_ONE")); personDTO.setIdTypeCd(rs.getString("COL_TWO")); return personDTO; }`

Comment: @Holger:  The interface `mapRow()` method throws the   `sqlException` but as we are overriding it don't we need to handle exception in `lambda`...

Comment: @holger: then we have to handle exception using `try` `catch` within `lambda` or `throws`  the exception in the `parent method` where `lambda exression` lies.Isn't it ?

Comment: @Kalanka the *caller* has to handle the exception, which is not necessarily the method containing the lambda expression. So in this example, it depends on the declaration of `query`. If this method declares the exception, because it’s relaying exceptions throw in the lambda expression’s body to the caller, then the method invoking `query` must handle the exception, which is the containing method here. Due to the formal rules, it has to handle the declared exception, even if you put a `try … catch …` into the lambda expression. A counter-example is `executorService.submit(() -> /* throwing */)`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    List<PersonDTO> personList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, (rs,rowNumber) -> {
              try
                {PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO ();
                personDTO.setPerId(rs.getString("COL_ONE"));  
                personDTO.setIdTypeCd(rs.getString("COL_TWO")); 
                return personDTO;
               }catch(SQLException e){ 
                  throw new RuntimeException("your error message",e) // or other unchecked exception here
               }
        });
```

Comment: what about `SQLException` that IIRC is a checked exception

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException(e)` *not* `throw RuntimeExcpetion(e)` (notice your typo also)